# vim git plugin для подсветки изменений в коде

Tags: git, vim

Нужен vim-плагин для git, который подсвечивал бы линии в коде, которые были изменены.

Comment: vimdiff подойдет ?

Comment: первый результат на поисковый запрос "vim plugin git highlight": https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter

Comment: Ваша техника поиска безупречна. То что надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

есть, например, такой *plugin*: https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

показывает модифицированные, удалённые и добавленные строки.